# How to create a calculated item using item.create?

Tags: zabbix

I am familiar with creating a calculated item with the GUI, but now I want to do it with the API. There is a "formula" field for an item object, but its type is int/float as stated in the document. So where do I put the formula needed by a calculated item?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxjDQ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [Zabbix manual](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.4/manual/api/reference/item/object), it's the `params` field.

Answer (score 0):

The string that you fill in "params" goes to "Formula"

*Tested on version 6*

```
"params": "last(//mysql.innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total) - 
    last(//mysql.innodb_buffer_pool_pages_free)"
```

Full context:

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "method": "item.create",
    "params": {
        "name": "MySQL: Buffer pool utilization",
        "key_": "mysql.buffer_pool_utilization",
        "params": "last(//mysql.innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total) - 
last(//mysql.innodb_buffer_pool_pages_free)"
        "hostid": "30074",
        "type": 15,
        "value_type": 3,
        "interfaceid": "30084",
        "tags": [
            {
                "tag": "Disc usage"
            },
            {
                "tag": "Equipment",
                "value": "Workstation"
            }
        ],
        "delay": "30s"
    },
    "auth": "038e1d7b1735c6a5436ee9eae095879e",
    "id": 1
}
```